# C++ Language Issue (Motivated By Google Protocol Buffer Application)

Tags: c++, networking, c++11, protocol-buffers

My question is probably just a simple question about using the c++ language, but the background/motivation involves networking code, so I'll include it

Background:

I have an application with a bunch of balls moving around according to various rules.  There is a server and a client that should be as synchronized as possible about the state of each ball.

I'm using Google's Protocol Buffers to create message objects that allow the client to set up or update each ball.  Balls have different states, and each ball might need to be transmitted to the client using a different message class generated by GPB. For example, one type of ball updates its position using a fixed acceleration vector, so the message corresponding to that type of ball would have position,velocity, and acceleration.

I want to store these message objects in a data structure that organizes them by position, so that clients can access only message objects that are nearby.  But each message has a different class type, so I don't know how to correctly put them all in a structure.

If I were hand-writing the message classes, I would make them all be subclasses of an abstract Message base object, with an enum type member.  Then I would store the messages as unique_ptrs to the abstract class and then do a static cast by the type enum whenever I needed to work with each object individually.  Ideally, since I need to serialize the message objects (they each have a serializeToOutputStream(..)) function, I would make this function an abstract member of the base class and have each of the particular message classes override it, so that I could avoid a cast in some situations.

The problem is that I am not hand-writing these classes.  They are generated by google's compiler.  I'm sure such a situation has arisen before, so I wonder how I should deal with it in an elegant way, if there is one.

Language-Only Version of Question:

I have a fixed set of generated classes A,B,C,D... that all have a few common functions like serializeToStream().  It would be very tedious to alter these classes since their sources are generated by a compiler.  I would like to store unique pointers or raw pointers to these objects in a data structure of some kind, like an std::map or std::vector, but I don't know how to do this.  If possible it would be great to call some of the functions that they all have without knowing which particular class I was dealing with (such as if I call the serialize function on all of them in a vector).

Comment: Do you know what type erasure is, and have you considered it?

Comment: @Yakk I've never heard of it, but I'll go read about it now to see if it helps.  Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR but I'm guessing if your post contains an actual question it is be something like _"I have unrelated classes `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` and need to store them in a container and access them later. How do I do that?"_

Comment: The Google protobuf C++ API already has a common, abstract base class for message type classes. Use that.

Answer (score -1):

There is not good way to solve your problem. Only nasty haks. For example you can store pointer to object and pointer to method of some fake type in your map. But then you must cast your classes and pointers of its methods by reinterpret to this fake type. You must remember that all who will read that your code will scold you and may be better to find the approach to create common base.